# Handling incorrect methods in AIOHTTP

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

For simplicity, let's use a simple AIOHTTP app

```
from aiohttp import web

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                web.get('/{name}', handle)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

When I run `curl -X incorrect_method http://localhost:8080` I obviously expect to get an error because incorrect_method isn't a valid method. The error I get is

```
Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fionn/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 334, in data_received
    messages, upgraded, tail = self._request_parser.feed_data(data)
  File "aiohttp/_http_parser.pyx", line 551, in aiohttp._http_parser.HttpParser.feed_data
aiohttp.http_exceptions.BadStatusLine: 400, message="Bad status line 'Invalid method encountered'"
```

I'm unsure how to **gracefully** handle this error without a traceback. I've tried to use CORS AIOHTTP middleware to limit incoming methods such as:

```
app = web.Application(middlewares=[cors_middleware(allow_methods=("POST"))])
```

but this is still allowing the problem to occur. Any suggestions how to prevent any incoming method that is not POST would be appreciated

Comment: CORS can't be used like that, it just tells browsers if the method can be called from javascript. It has no effect on direct requests like via curl.

Comment: Possibly related. AIOTTP has a tendency to throw for invalid data rather than handling errors. https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/6706

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer can be found here https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3287

The actual problem seems to be validating the http request as a proper request. This has to be done outside of aiohttp it seems.